# How can I put an Apostroph (') in the charfilter function?

Tags: solr

The `Charfilter` from Solr doesn't work for some reason when I try to convert Apostrophs.
This is the format of the `Charfilter`:

```
"ê" => "e" | works

"’" => "'" | doesn't work
```

The goal is that when you search for example "d'oranges" you also get results like "d’oranges".

Comment: can you try by adding a backslash followed by character

Comment: Thanks alot for your response and the edit!

"\’" => "\'"

Do you mean like this? I just tried that, sadly it didn't work.

Comment: Does it help to specify the characters in Unicode like this? `"\u2019" ⇒ "\u0027"`
Also, the docs use an arrow character (`⇒`) where you've used a two-character sequence (`=>`). Would that be an important difference?

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't work.
I just tried it again - same result.
The arrow shouldn't be a problem, as all other filters work. Actually when I use the arrow charater the entire Solr search doesn't work anymore...